# Me da errores de que las variables no están definidas

Tags: javascript, php, sql, jquery, datatables

Me da errores en el código php de que no están definidas 1 variable, cuando no es asi, en el ajax está definida antes para insertarlo.
En el código php no se llega a mover los archivos, ahí es donde tengo el problema, ya que si se pudieran mover lo tendría resuelto.

Si se necesita más parte del código puedo ofrecerla en cualquier momento.

El archivo de javascript es bastante más grande, tengo las funciones de elinminar, mostrar, cancelar y guardar por si se necesitan en algún momento.

javascript.js, este se encarga de leer los datos editados en la datatable y enviarlos a editar_arboles.php para que este los suba y los actualice en la base de datos.

```
table.on('click', '.edit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            nNew = false;

            var nRow = $(this).parents('tr')[0];

            if (nEditing == nRow) {
                saveRow(oTable, nEditing);
                getParamsEditRow(oTable, nRow);
                nEditing = null;
                ajax = objetoAjax1();

                ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {

                    if (ajax.readyState == 4){

                        alert("ya está terminado el ajax");

                        var datos_obtenidos;
                        datos_obtenidos = (ajax.responseText);
                        alert(datos_obtenidos);
                    }
                } 
                var tabla1 = $("#tabla1").val();
                var myData = new FormData();
                myData.append("id", id);
                myData.append("tipo", tipo);
                myData.append("altura_metros", altura);
                myData.append("tiempo_de_vida", vida);
                myData.append("descripcion", desc);
                myData.append("centro", centro);
                myData.append("foto", foto);

                $.ajax({
                url : "editar_arboles.php",
                    method : "POST",
                    type : "POST",
                    data : myData,
                    contentType : false,
                    processData : false,
                    dataType : "html",
                    success : alert(foto)
                    });
            } else {

                editRow(oTable, nRow);
                nEditing = nRow;


            }
        });
```

y el de subir los archivos editar_arboles.php

```
<?php
include ("conexion.php");
$conexion->set_charset("utf8");
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$dirname = $_SESSION['centro_id'];
$carpeta_destino ="/brocal/v2/alcorque/IMAGENES/" . $dirname;

$id = $_POST['id'];
$altura = $_POST['altura_metros'];
$vida = $_POST['tiempo_de_vida'];
$desc = $_POST['descripcion'];
$foto = $_FILES['foto'];
$centro = $_POST['centro'];
$file = $foto['tmp_name'];
$foto_name = $foto['name'];
$ruta = $carpeta_destino . $foto_name;


$permitidos = array("image/jpg", "image/gif", "image/jpeg", "image/png");

if (in_array($foto['type'], $permitidos)) {
    move_uploaded_file($file, $ruta);
    echo "holahola";
} else {
    echo "Ha ocurrido un error.";
}
$sql = "UPDATE proyecto_arbol.arboles 
    SET altura_metros='$altura', tiempo_de_vida='$vida', descripcion='$desc', centro='$centro', foto='$ruta'
    WHERE id='$id'";

if (mysqli_query($conexion, $sql)){
    echo "Ok";
} else {
    echo "A ocurrido un error";
}
?>
```

Comment: deberías mostrarnos el código de tus intentos, cuál es tu intención, qué esperabas que sucediera, y qué es lo que obtienes y que no funciona. Lee con atención **toda** la información de la página https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Comment: Ahora mismo se puede subir, pero no se me actualiza en la base de datos.

Comment: Me da unos errores de que no esta definido cuando no es asi.

Comment: que variables dice que no estan definidas?

Comment: las lineas 14, 16, 17 y 23, las que tienen que ver con $foto

Comment: revisa por favor todo el texto de tu pregunta, sigue las convenciones y recomendaciones, y en concreto, mírate bien https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
tal como lo cuentas, es muy difícil entender tu problema.
Qué quieres conseguir? cómo lo intentas? qué problema tienes?

Comment: ¿¿Exactamente qué variables no están definidas??.

Comment: Lo que estoy intentando es cambiar la foto de una datatable a través de un ajax y un post, el problema es que cuando el archivo php recibe el post no detecta la variable $foto, por lo tanto no se me actualiza en la base de datos

Comment: Estos son los errores que me da Warning: Undefined array key "foto" in /.../editar_arboles.php on line 14

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /.../editar_arboles.php on line 16

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /.../editar_arboles.php on line 17

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /.../editar_arboles.php on line 23